# How to change external links color inside class

Tags: css

is possible change color external links inside some class? I tried this:

```css
.space-page-content a {
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
.space-page-content a[href^="http://"]:not([href*="mywebsite.com"]):after,
.space-page-content a[href^="https://"]:not([href*="mywebsite.com"]):after{
   background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<a style="space-page-content" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/page-1/" >internal</a><br>
<a style="space-page-content" href="http://www.google.com" >external</a><br>
<a style="space-page-content" href="http://www.mywebsite.com" >internal</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in your CSS and HTML code,

1. in CSS `.space-page-content` defined as class, while in your HTML its something else.
2. also when your write like this `.space-page-content a` , this means that `a` is a child inside your parent `.space-page-content`. But in fact, your HTML says that this class is given to `a`, so you should say *select 'a' that has class 'space-page-content'* by this way `a.space-page-content` without any spaces between `a` and your class.
3. you want to change the background of your `a` , so no need to add `:after`.

```css
a.space-page-content{
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
a.space-page-content[href^="http://"]:not([href*="mywebsite.com"]),
a.space-page-content[href^="https://"]:not([href*="mywebsite.com"]){
   background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<a class="space-page-content" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/page-1/" >internal</a><br>
<a class="space-page-content" href="http://www.google.com" >external</a><br>
<a class="space-page-content" href="http://www.mywebsite.com" >internal</a>
```